# Maven install :update-alternatives: error

Tags: java, maven-3

While installing maven in Ubuntu 18.04 in with command

```
sudo apt install maven
```

i am getting error like

```
update-alternatives: error: alternative link /usr/bin/mvn is already managed by maven
dpkg: error processing package maven (--configure):
 installed maven package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 maven
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and i tried second option
following steps in this link https://www.javahelps.com/2017/10/install-apache-maven-on-linux.html

```
in step 5
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/mvn" "mvn" "/opt/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin/mvn" 0
sudo update-alternatives --set mvn /opt/apache-maven-3.6.3/bin/mvn
```

got same error.

Answer (score 0):

I tried `update-alternatives --remove mvn /usr/bin/mvn` **and** `update-alternatives --remove-all mvn`
It worked